# What do we call the case when the subject is preceded by the verb that refers to?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

> There ***comes*** a ***point*** where you just love someone, not because they're good or bad You just love them the way they are.

In this sentence the verb "comes" came before the subject "point", so when we could use this condition?

Comment: It is called **inversion**. Here, the inversion is caused by **There**.   "There" + verb + subject.  *There is a house at the top of the hill.*

Answer (score 2):

This type of inversion happens when a sentence starts with an expression of place or direction, especially to present a new subject.

> §303 **inversion** (2): whole verb before subject
>
> **1 after adverbial expressions of place**
>   ... intransitive verbs are often put before their subjects. The structure is most common in literary and descriptive writing.
>
> - *Under a tree **was lying** one of the biggest men I had ever seen.*
>
> This structure is often used in speech with *here*, *there* and other short adverbs and adverb particles.
>
> - *There **goes** your brother.*
>
> (From Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*)